# Ajuda para migrar de Actionbar.Tabs para ViewPager por causa da API 21

Tags: android, actionbar

Pelo que eu entendi de leve, a hospedagem de tabs na actionbar ficou obsoleta na API 21. Ainda não entendi muito bem porque (se alguém explicar melhor eu agradeço) mas o que posso fazer é me adaptar.
Fiz uma pesquisa e descobri algumas alternativas como a **Sliding Tabs** do Google Play com ViewPager, apesar de eu nunca ter usado ViewPager porque a Actionbar.Tab me servia muito bem.

Mas estou com alguns problemas e dúvidas na implementação porque essa ferramenta parece ser muito boa para tabs estáticas. O caso é que o meu app tem as tabs muito dinâmicas. Em virtude de ser um app de chat com cada conversa sendo exibida por um fragment, novas tabs surgem e são removidas a todo momento.

Eu não consegui alinhar muito bem a estratégia do ViewPager com este cenário. Percebi que a maneira como o adapter identifica a tab selecionada é muito diferente do tablistener da actionbar e também não encontrei métodos que adicionassem ou removessem tabs no adapter ou no SlidingTabs. Pensei em armazenar os fragments em um Arraylist para ser usado pelo adapter mas não sei se o adapter identificaria quando eu removesse ou adicionasse um fragment de lá.
Outra questão que dinamiza as tabs é que os nicks dos usuários relativos à conversa são exibido nelas, e esse nick também pode mudar a qualquer momento. Não sei ao certo quando o método getPageTitle() é chamado.

Pensando nessas diferenças decidi vir aqui pedir ajuda pois talvez haja até uma alternativa melhor para este caso que eu ainda não conheço ou alguma boa prática que deixe esse cenário viável.

**Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Desde já, muito obrigado.**

Answer (score 2):

Olá, primeiro eu gostaria de dizer sobre a minha experiência em relação a Fragments dinâmicos dentro do ViewPager e posso te dizer que não é uma boa idéia. Não tenho idéia de como é o seu app mas se conselho fosse bom (rsrs) eu diria pra você pensar em como funcionam a maioria dos apps de mensagens (hangouts, fb messenger, whatsapp, telegram, etc.), onde existe um Fragment que lista as conversas e outro Fragment/Activity que mostra a conversa. Também penso na usabilidade, por exemplo: Eu tenho 10 Tabs/Conversas abertas e pra poder abrir a 9º eu preciso ficar rolando o ViewPager até chegar lá O_o

Mas esclarecendo como funciona o ViewPager, você deve pensar na estrutura dele. Primeiro o xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/color_primary_darker"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsPaddingMiddle="false"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Bem simples onde você indica onde ficará as Tabs (título ou qualquer layout que você quiser) e o seu ViewPager que é onde serão adicionados todos os seus Fragments.

Depois, no Fragment/Activity que você quiser implementar o ViewPager você deve criar um Adapter para ele e setar o ViewPager no SlidingTab:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mPagerTab = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabtitles, mDrawable));
mPagerTab.setViewPager(mPager);
```

E um exemplo simples de um FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String titles[];

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] titles) {
        super(fm);
        titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return SampleFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return SampleFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return SampleFragment.newInstance();

        }
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

O que determina a quantidade de Fragments no ViewPager, neste* caso é o field PAGE_COUNT;

É possível sim você ficar mudando a quantidade de Fragments no seu Adapter para isso você precisa criá-lo passando como parâmetro a quantidade de Fragments que você quer e uma lista com os Fragments que você deseja utilizar. Ou você também pode criar esses métodos dentro do Adapter, modificá-los e informar ao controlador pelo método `notifyDataSetChanged();` do Adapter.

Neste exemplo eu usei o framework https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Então, no meu caso esse PAGE_COUNT já não poderia ser final, ele vai variar.
E pra eu entender melhor, caso eu queira adicionar ou remover uma tab, da certo eu ter um Arraylist<Fragment> para armazenar os fragments e caso ocorra alguma alteração, eu chamo o notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Isto mesmo. Funciona da mesma forma como você pode fazer em uma ListView com um BaseAdapter

Comment: Olhando dessa forma pode até ficar mais simples do que com actionbar.tabs. Isto é, se funcionar.

Comment: Rafael, como eu faço para saber o indice ou titulo da tab selecionada?

Comment: Você pode usar o método `getCurrentItem()` do ViewPager que retorna um inteiro.

Comment: Você poderia me dizer qual a diferença dessa sliding tabs do jpardogo para a do astuetz e qual eu deveria usar e pq?
Muito obrigado Rafael.

Comment: Basicamente a do jpardogo é baseado no Material Design e a do astuetz no Tema Holo (tema padrão do ICS, JB e KK)